# Accessing and saving a field that is not included in fields attribute in extending generic class-based CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to display the user a form with comments not included. When the user submits the form, then, I want to manually add something to my comments, and then only, saving the object. With default implementation, it doesn't do anything with comments.

! app/views.py

```py
class ContactUsView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Contact
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address']
    success_message = "Thank you for your enquiry. We' ll be in touch shortly."
```

! app/models.py

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    email_address = models.EmailField()
    comments = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('contact')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by [overriding](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid) the `form_valid` function of your view.

```py
class ContactUsView(SuccessMessageMixin, CreateView):
    model = Contact
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email_address']
    success_message = "Thank you for your enquiry. We' ll be in touch shortly."

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.comments = 'Your comments here' 
        self.object.save()
        return super(ContactUsView, self).form_valid(form)
```

You can also do this by [overriding](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods) the `save()` method of your model `Contact`

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    # your fields here

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # check if it's a new object
        if not self.id:
            self.comments = 'Your comment'
        super(Contact, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I have a doubt. The default implementation of form_valid() as per [link](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.11/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/#form_valid), save the object again and then calls the form_valid() in its super class. ie., FormMixin which then redirects to success_url. So, will it make the object hitting the database twice. Please let me know.

Comment: You can have a look at django's example in the above link. I don't think calling super() will hit the database twice.